# R:How to select the amount of data in a dataset by a given variable

Tags: r

Let's take dataset `iris` and there is static value `g=101`. Iris dataset has 150 value.
How to select exactly as many observations in the `iris` dataset as indicated in the variable `g` starting from the very first observation?
As final result will be iris dataset ,but with 101 obs.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `seq_len` on 'g' and use as row index

```
g <- 101
iris_sub <- iris[seq_len(g),]
```

-output

```
> dim(iris_sub)
[1] 101   5
```

Answer (score 1):

in a dataframe, isn't this the basic  `df[1: n,]` will select all records from 1 to N and all columns if none is specified. (If you have modified the data - say sorted etc and saved, it will show saved result]

so `iris[1:g,]` will itself work. No need for anything more with `g <- 101`